# Rollback database to old one without backup

Tags: sql-server, restore

I accidentally restored an SQL Server database from the wrong backup using the following statement:

```
RESTORE DATABASE  [" + conn.Database + "] FROM DISK='" + path_backup + "'"
```

This is the exact query I used. I'm not an expert, so I don't really know why this worked, but it actually did.

I did not use `REPLACE`. Is there any way that I can rollback to previous state of the database? I've read that `REPLACE` overwrites the database, does this mean that if I don't use it, there is a copy somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "No".

If you have restored from backup then you have overwritten your database.

The only way to get your database back is to restore from a suitable backup.

If your database is in full recovery mode and you have the last full backup and subsequent transaction logs you may be able to do a point in time recovery to  a point more acceptable than when the last full backup was taken.

The `REPLACE` option is just a safeguard against accidentally overwriting the existing database with a backup taken from a different database. The restore will not be allowed in that case otherwise.